# ¿Se dice “El administración” o “la administración”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género, artículos, terminología

Escuchando un programa de Ecuador he observado que el presentador usó la expresión “el administración del tiempo”.

Buscando en internet encontré las ambas formas de articulación ([*"el administracion"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22el+administraci%C3%B3n%22&oq=%22el+administraci%C3%B3n%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l4j69i60l3.3938j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

> [image]

Quería preguntar cuál es la forma correcta/recomendada: *la administración* o *el administración*?

Comment: *la administración* se pronuncia /lad.mi.nis.tra'θjon/. Si hubiese una vocal /e/ antes, como sería el caso de «de la administración», sería /de.lad.mi.nis.tra'θjon/, que es la mismísima pronunciación que tendría «del administración».  No encuentro ningún ejemplo de *el administración* por Google que no parezca un error de tecleo.

Comment: Al ser un nombre femenino [de acuerdo al DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/administraci%C3%B3n) debería is con "la" y no "el". Es curioso que se advierte que administración va con mayúsculas en su cuarta acepción ("Conjunto de los organismos de gobierno de una nación ") y en los ejemplos se capitaliza no solo la a inicial de administración, sino también la del artículo: "Su lucha contra LA Administración. LA Administración autonómica"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como recogen algunos de los resultados de tu búsqueda en Google, y otros ejemplos presentes en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) y [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html), por existir, existen casos con el artículo masculino: **el administración**.

En algunos casos parece que es el artículo "el" cuando en realidad es un acrónimo, como en [Elia Lozano Portugués - E.L. Administración de Fincas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi899Dm3ZjqAhULkRQKHUDSDQgQFjAIegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Felialozano&usg=AOvVaw3YJGUpi4IEvEzrh7BxQ0K8) y otros podrían ser, como señala guifa, errores de tecleo (por ejemplo, [este caso del BOE](https://boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=BOE-A-1995-24470), pero otras veces parece un claro uso deliberado, como [este caso](https://books.google.es/books?id=1tWO6kPzohAC&pg=PP3&lpg=PP3&dq=%22el%20administraci%C3%B3n%22&source=bl&ots=9rd9UqqLE_&sig=ACfU3U0BVEc9rg7JoZ1mvjFajUXNsdLWWQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigqd7q3JjqAhVt5OAKHcGCCw04ChDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%22el%20administraci%C3%B3n%22&f=false) o [este otro](https://books.google.es/books?id=K_BqCwsEEqkC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=%22el%20administraci%C3%B3n%22&source=bl&ots=Zl3WOYxkh1&sig=ACfU3U3MK2Y3dMCbeYLL8Y51CcGnleLbMg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigqd7q3JjqAhVt5OAKHcGCCw04ChDoATACegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22el%20administraci%C3%B3n%22&f=false), especialmente en textos antiguos.

Sin embargo, como sabiamente indica @Diego, lo correcto *hoy día* es con el articulo femenino: **la administración**.

Comment: Salvo una excepción (alción), todos los sustantivos que terminan en -ción son femeninos.