# ¿Por qué está en mayúscula esta "a" en el ejemplo del DLE "LA Administración"?

Tags: dle, uso-de-mayúsculas, diccionarios

Haciendo una consulta rápida en el DRAE al respecto de la pregunta en [¿Se dice “El administración” o “la administración”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35032/5481) vi en [la entrada del DRAE para "administración"](https://dle.rae.es/administraci%C3%B3n) la nota "Escr. con may. inicial en acep. 4." (escrito con mayúscula en la acepción cuarta) y en esa misma acepción el ejemplo

> [image: No me lo invento]

> Su lucha contra LA Administración. LA Administración autonómica.

No entiendo ni que vaya en mayúsculas la "a" de "L**A** Administración autonómica" ni el "LA" de "Su lucha contra **LA** Administración".

¿Se debe esto a algo que no entiendo referente a esa nota del DLE acerca del uso de la mayúscula cuando usamos "administración" refiriéndonos a los organismo de gobierno? ¿Es una errata dentro del diccionario online? ¿Un error del código que presenta la información (he probado con Chrome y Firefox y los dos navegadores lo enseñan con mayúsculas)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el DLE, con frecuencia aparecen en mayúsculas las preposiciones que vienen regidas por verbos. Por ejemplo, en la entrada para [pensar](https://dle.rae.es/pensar):

> 3. tr. Opinar algo acerca de una persona o cosa. *¿Qué piensas DE él?*
>
> [...]
>
> 5. intr. Formar en la mente un juicio u opinión sobre algo. *No pienses más EN este asunto.*
> 6. intr. Recordar o traer a la mente algo o a alguien. *Me esforzaba en no pensar EN ella.*

Como he escrito en un comentario a la otra respuesta, el código fuente correspondiente a estas palabras en mayúsculas es

```
<span class="i1">de</span>
```

y en el CSS vemos que la clase "i1" incluye la siguiente regla de estilo

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

así que las mayúsculas son normalmente intencionadas. En el caso de "LA administración", hay dos posibilidades: o bien al que escribió la entrada le pareció importante resaltar que hay que usar el artículo aunque se trate de un nombre propio en esa acepción, o bien es realmente un desliz.

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar confirmo que se ve así en algunos otros navegadores (Internet Explorer 6, Mypal). Sin entender gran cosa de informática, me atrevo a suponer que es un problema del código, ya que en lo que se muestra con "Mostrar código fuente de la página" (o equivalente, según el navegador) *siempre* aparece **La Administración** y nunca **LA Administración**.

Por ejemplo (línea 11, negrita mía):

`<meta name="description" content="1. f. Acción y efecto de administrar. 2. f. Cargo o actividad del administrador. 3. f. Oficina o despacho del administrador. 4. f. Conjunto de los organismos de gobierno de una nación o de una entidad política inferior. Su lucha contra la Administración. La Administración autonómica."`

Comment: Lo que hay dentro de una etiqueta "meta" no tiene efecto sobre la página en sí, sino sobre cómo aparece en la búsqueda de Google, por ejemplo. Si buscas más abajo, verás que el código correspondiente a la parte citada es "<mark data-id="ESraxkH|MiZ5vEt|NWnohQu"><span class="i1">la</span></mark> <mark data-id="0mCOzj6">Administraci&#xF3;n</mark>", y por su parte la clase "i1" transforma su contenido en mayúsculas. La manera más fácil de ver esto es hacer clic derecho en la palabra "LA" y dar a "Inspect element".

Comment: La razón de que el código sea tan complicado es el hecho de que cada palabra es un link a su entrada en el diccionario. Pero lo de <span class="i1">la</span> hace pensar que las mayúsculas son intencionadas.